# Difference between 'number % 2:' and 'number % 2 == 0'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning about Python's boolean logic and how you can shorten things down.  Are the two expressions in the title equivalent?  If not, what are the differences between them?

Comment: FirebladeDan... both evaluate to the remainder, and both evaluate to either True or False. Inherently, if there's a remainder, it evaluates to True. If there isn't a remainder, it evaluates to False. You can just as well do `if 5 % 2 == True` or `if 4 % 2 == False`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`number % 2` is 0 (so False) if number is even

`number % 2 == 0` is True is number is even

The first returns an `int` where the second returns a `bool`. Python's [truthiness](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) lets you handle them the same though.

Comment: #Pro. Learned something today

Comment: Basically `not num % 2` is the same as `number % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 2):

`number % 2`

is equal to (shorthand for)

`number % 2 != 0`

because 1 evaluates to True and 0 to False.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple. you can try on your terminal:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> if 5%2:
...     print "T"
... 
T
>>> if 5%2 == 0:
...     print "T"
... 
>>>
```

1) if condition looks for answer >1.
2) In a) you're looking if answer is >1 
   in b) you're looking if answer == 0 (if so like in all other language == will return 1)